# unexpected token import - angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-universal

I'm trying to run angular universal using [this starter](https://github.com/evertonrobertoauler/cli-universal-demo) but at least one of my packages is giving the issue of "unexpected token import". Right now it's the [angular2 toaster package](https://github.com/Stabzs/Angular2-Toaster).

Apparently if I go into the node_modules folder and edit the compiled files to change the  "import" statements to "require" it starts working, though this means there's some kind of configuration issue.

Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

angular2-toaster needed to be added to nodeExternals as whitelist.

1. if using angular-cli, use `ng eject` to create a webpack.config.js
2. install the `webpack-node-externals` dependency via `npm install` and add the following line to the `module.exports` of the `webpack.config.js` file

`target: 'node',
   externals: [nodeExternals({
     whitelist: [
       /^@ng-bootstrap\/ng-bootstrap/,
       /^angular2\-toaster/,
     ]
   })],`